# jq click() not happening as expected

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

Function with `click()` works but when using it is in a switch case break scenario it does not do the click(), but alerts as expected?

```
function about() {
    alert('ABOUT!');
    $('.butin').click(); //This is not clicking as expected
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/7zaLyaLz/)

Comment: .trigger('click') instead of .click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering the click before binding it.

Correct order is:

```
...
$('.butin').click(function() { // bind the click handler
    alert("clicked!")
});

if (val) {
    goTo(val); // now you can trigger it
}
...
```

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zaLyaLz/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code block

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".butin").click(function(){        
        alert('ABOUT!');    
    });
});
```